# ARIA Enabled ComboBox Issue

Tags: combobox, extjs4.2, wai-aria

ARIA enabled combobox gives me

> TypeError: a is undefined

in Firefox whenever I click on the trigger. And obviously with the error clicking the trigger doesn't show any data.

Disabling ARIA, it works fine.

In Chrome, I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isVisible' of undefined ext-aria.js:1
Ext.define.getErrorTipOwner ext-aria.js:1
Ext.define.onFocus ext-aria.js:1
Base.implement.callParent ext-all-debug.js:4266
Ext.define.onFocus ext-all-debug.js:87675
Base.implement.callParent ext-all-debug.js:4266
Ext.define.onFocus ext-all-debug.js:92499
Ext.define.onTriggerClick ext-all-debug.js:97364
Ext.define.onTriggerWrapClick ext-all-debug.js:92583
(anonymous function) VM122:6
wrap
```

Again Firefox' error:

```
TypeError: a is undefined
...rm.FieldContainer",ariaRole:"group",ariaGetEl:function(){return this.getTargetEl...
```

On using ext-aria-debug.js the error is on the following

```
TypeError: tip is undefined


if (tip.isVisible()) {
```

This is where the error is:

```
getErrorTipOwner: function() {
    var tip = this.tip;

    if (tip.isVisible()) {
        return tip.ownerField;
    }

    return null;
},
```

Comment: Looks like it can't find `ext-aria.js`. Did you include it properly?

Comment: Thanks forgivenson... but it seems all my form fields(textbox, textarea, radiobutton) act the same way when it's focused or when I click on them. Please see my update